# what is Boundary Value Analysis?

Tags: testing

In an eCommerce website, the first name text field accepts a maximum of 30 characters, What are the BVA values?

Comment: Please share more details. How should we know what these values are? Why not ask whoever maintains that website?

Comment: The Options are : 
29,30,31
25,30,31
15,29,30
10,20,30

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

Boundary values are the thresholds where a program behaves differently.

For instance, suppose I am sending messages. Each message must be split into packets of between 1 and 100 bytes. If the message is 100 bytes then one packet should be sent. If the message is 101 bytes then two packets should be sent. There is a boundary between 100 and 101 bytes. Both lengths should be tested.

Bugs typically happen at boundary values because that is where off-by-one errors and similar problems exist. In the message example above, you might find that a 100 byte message gets sent as two packets, or a 101 byte message drops the last byte, because of some subtle bug in the packet logic. This might happen even though shorter or longer messages get sent correctly, which is why it is important to concentrate on boundary values when testing.

Boundary Value Analysis is the process of identifying boundary values, both by inspecting the specification and inspecting the code. Look for conditions on things like length and range. For instance, if a field must be all letters then check values like 'a' (0x61), '`' (backtick, 0x60), 'z' (0x7a) and '{' (0x7b). If a field must not be more than 30 characters, check 30 and 31. And so on.

(Also, don't forget that Unicode is a thing: check non-English and non-Latin characters too).